# Where should Model reside in case of 3-tier Domain Driven designed application?

Tags: c#, silverlight, wcf, domain-driven-design, dto

In a typical business oriented thin client application (in my case Silverlight) where should Domain Model reside on server side or client side or both in respect to Domain Driven Design. Should I operate with my Domain Entities or DTO's on client side?

What if my application supports "server-less" mode, when it doesn't communicate with server except for downloading application. Currently my server-less mode is transparent to application, I'm still using same service interfaces but provide local implementation of them.

Comment: Um, could you specify the meaning of 'Where'? You say you have a local implementation for services. Well, it should be quite natural for these services to include both Business Layer and Data Access Layer (living on the client). Does this answer your question? If not, please, clarify your concerns.

Comment: I depends, ofthen it resides on Server side since server side is aware of DB structure and initially created entities from DB, but client application uses entities as well.

Comment: Is there any reason you are not using RIA services? It is after all just a client-proxy generator on top of WCF. When I say "just" it is actually pretty darn cool :)

Comment: @HiTech Yes, it's to simple for our project.

Comment: "Thin client" by definition means that the service holds the actual implementation of the domain model.  Thin = thin domain model.  No matter what, you're going to need some model of the domain on both, otherwise your client code and UI would be incomprehensible :)  But with a "thin client", that client-side copy of the domain model will defer to the server for resolution of business rules and business logic whenever possible/sensible.

Answer (score 2):

Well they can stay in both places. You could have:

1) Rich fat client with a full domain and having repository accessing the back end through ODATA or something.
2) Thin client making access to the server through command and DTO and only implementing couple of validation
3) and a mix of both.

There is no single response, unfortunately, one project is not the other. It is a question of context.

If you provided more information we could try to help you choose.

Answer (score 0):

You should create your model in a separate Assembly, and reference it from both Client and Server.
This way you will be able to access the model from both parts of your program easily, while separating it from your graphic and business logic.

Comment: This won't work since Silverlight cannot reference .Net assemblies. There are 2 solutions: use WCF RIA Services, or reuse source code files with the help of links.